# Unity 3.5.1404 PDBs

Tags: .net, nuget, pdb-files

My question is where can I get the PDBs for Unity 3.5.1404?

Up to version 2.1, I could get an MSI with the DLLs, source, PDBs, but with Nuget, I could only get the DLLs. I googled around and found SymbolSource.org, and the site appears to have the sources but I couldn’t get the integration with Visual Studio (2012 and 2015) to download the PDBs.

Following the instructions (http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio) I could get Visual Studio to try and download the symbols but it never found them (http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public always returns 404). What’s the recommended way to get package symbols downloaded with Nuget?

Comment: Unity is now [open source](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity).  You could download the source, build it, and reference the dll / pdb from that local build.  (At least for temporary debugging purposes.)

Comment: Thanks. The version that I'm interested is indeed part of the open source project. I've been dwelling with the PublicKeyToken, but it looks promising